# How to prompt user to switch metamask wallet address in a web3 app

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am working on a web3 web app. I have a case where I will need to ask user to change to a different wallet address, other than the one he/she is connected with at the moment. But when I call `eth_requestAccounts`, metamask simply returns the connected address without prompting user to switch to a new one.

How might I prompt user to switch address in metamask? thanks.